# Can you pass data to a test fixture just like you pass data to test cases?

Tags: nunit

Can you pass data to a NUnit3 test fixture just like you pass data to test cases?
Would it even make sense to do this? (run a suite (fixture class) based on a parameter)

Answer (score 10):

Absolutely!

If there's a limited amount of parameters you need to pass in, you can just put these in the normal `[TestFixture]` attribute, and they will be passed to the constructor of the TestFixture. e.g.

```cs
[TestFixture("hello", "hello", "goodbye")]
[TestFixture("zip", "zip", "zap")]
public class ParameterizedTestFixture
{
    private string eq1;
    private string eq2;
    private string neq;

    public ParameterizedTestFixture(string eq1, string eq2, string neq)
    {
        this.eq1 = eq1;
        this.eq2 = eq2;
        this.neq = neq;
    }
}
```

This version would run the test fixture twice, with the two different sets of parameters. ([Docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixture-Attribute))

If you have more parameters, you may wish to look at `[TestFixtureSource]` - which works much the same way, but allows you to calculate your parameters in a static method, as opposed to explicity specified in an attribute. ([Docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixtureSource-Attribute)) Something such as this:

```cs
[TestFixtureSource(typeof(FixtureArgs))]
public class MyTestClass
{
    public MyTestClass(string word, int num) { ... }

    ...
}

class FixtureArgs: IEnumerable
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new object[] { "Question", 1 };
        yield return new object[] { "Answer", 42 };
    }
}
```

Finally, if you need to pass parameters in at run-time, this is also possible through the `--params` command line option, new in NUnit v3.4. It doesn't look like this is documented yet, but you can pass it into the NUnit console command line in the format `--params:X=5;Y=7"`. It can then be retrieved through the `TestContext.Parameters` class.

Comment: Note that of all the things Chris mentions, only TestFixture attribute is available if you are using NUnit 2. TestFixtureSource comes in with NUnit 3. The TestParameters things is obviously slightly different, as it does not allow you to pass different values to different fixtures. It provides general parameters that stay in effect for the whole run.