# Parameterizing test fixtures the way it's done with test methods

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

Following up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079476/can-you-pass-data-to-a-test-fixture-just-like-you-pass-data-to-test-cases) discussion, my question is:

Is it possible to parameterize test fixtures with something like `ValueSource` attribute used on test methods to make NUnit generate tests based on all possible combinations of input parameter values, but for test fixture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet possible with TestFixtures in NUnit. The best you can do is to use TestFixtureSource (https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixtureSource-Attribute) but that requires you to specify the combinations you want yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Charlie! I generated required parameter combinations and used them with TestFixtureSource. It works, but what about test case names in Test Explorer? They are all the same. Can I customize them using parameter names?

Comment: Yes. You can use a fixed string name per case or look at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Template-Based-Test-Naming

Comment: If I understand the template-based test naming it requires use of `TestCaseData`, but I don't use it. Is it possible to set custom test naming pattern at `TestFixtureSource` level, so all tests in the fixture are named accordingly?

Comment: No... that would be an interesting feature request, however.

Comment: So there is no other way or workaround to feed test data to test fixture and have test names that can be distinguished in Text Explorer?